# Erlang printing hex instead of integer

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have been trying to fix a problem for hours now, very new to erlang

```
lists:sublist([6,9,15,24,39,6,96],7,1).
```

I want this to print "100" instead of "d"

what I am i doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not hex, it's ASCII.

Comment: The actual value above is not ASCII "d". You've got a backtick at the moment (char value 96)...

Answer (score 5):

The shell is going to try to print strings as strings whenever it would be legal. That means lists of integers that happen to *all* be valid characters will be printed as characters, and lists that contain other things will be printed as lists:

```
1> [65,66,67].
"ABC"
2> [3,65,66,67].
[3,65,66,67]
```

But *notice that I did not actually call any output functions*. That was just the shell's convenience operation of implicitly echoing whatever a returned value was so you, as a programmer, can inspect it.

If I want to explicitly call an output function I should use a format string that specifies the nature of the values to be interpolated:

```
3> io:format("This is a list: ~tw~n", [List]).
This is a list: [65,66,67]
ok
4> io:format("This is a list rendered as an implied string: ~tp~n", [List]).
This is a list rendered as an implied string: "ABC"
ok
5> io:format("This is a string: ~ts~n", [List]).                            
This is a string: ABC
ok
```

Note the additional atom `ok` after each print. That is because the return value from `io:format/2` is `ok`. So we are getting the explicit output from `format/2` and then seeing its return value.

The io module doc page has the gritty details: http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1

Back to your example...

```
6> lists:sublist([6,9,15,24,39,6,96],7,1).
"`"
7> io:format("~tw~n", [lists:sublist([6,9,15,24,39,6,96],7,1)]).
[96]
ok
```

**Addendum**

There is a setting called [`shell:strings/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html#strings-1) that tells the shell to turn string formatting on and off:

```
1> [65,66,67].
"ABC"
2> shell:strings(false).
true
3> [65,66,67].
[65,66,67]
4> <<65,66,67>>.
<<65,66,67>>
5> shell:strings(true). 
false
6> <<65,66,67>>.       
<<"ABC">>
```

But I don't mess with this setting ever anymore for a few reasons:

- It is almost never worth the effort to remember this detail of the shell (convenience output from the shell is mostly useful for discovering return *value structures*, not *specific values* held by those structures -- and when you want that data you usually want strings printed as strings anyway).
- It can cause surprising shell output in any case where you really *are* dealing with strings.
- This is almost never the behavior you actually want.
- When dealing with real programs you will need actual output functions using `io` or `io_lib` modules, and developing habits around format strings is much more useful than worrying over convenience output from the shell.

Comment: I guess can add some information about function `shell:strings/1`.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Thanks for the reminder. I added a note about `shell:strings/1`. The main thing I wanted to express was the general method of using format strings, as it is universally useful forever, whereas shell convenience values are generally of just occasional use here and there when playing with an idea.